# running a function from a plugin via a URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a quick a plugin for wordpress at the minute and it's a function that needs to run via a CRON. I want to run the code from a URL like a see other plugins do,

> domain.com/wp-load.php?action=my_plugin_action

but I cannot work how to do that I know to run the function via ajax and the ajax url you would create an action, is it the same for the above URL?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. The WordPress entry point is the `index.php`, not the `wp-load.php`. Then, why don't you utilize the WordPress native cron system? You register the corn you want, you may customize the schedules you want the cron to run, then you point your server cron to `http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` and finally add this to your `wp-config.php`:  `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Execute PHP File Using a Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431018/how-execute-php-file-using-a-cron-job)